# Stop the sliding screen at the middle

Tags: java, android, xml

HomeActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    Button btnopen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnWindowAnimation);

    btnopen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent slideactivity = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, CartActivity.class);

    Bundle bndlanimation = 
            ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animation,R.anim.animation2).toBundle();
    startActivity(slideactivity, bndlanimation);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.home, menu);
    return true;
}
```

HomeActivity has a button and it will help to slide the 1st screen and bring the second screen.

animation.xml

```
android:fromXDelta="100%p"
android:toXDelta="25%p"
android:duration="5000"
```

This animation code is helping me to slide my screen after pressing the button. As shown in this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzgGGWpRES0

I want to stop the new screen at the middle without covering the 1st screen completely.
Any suggestions? I have used another activity called cart( i haven't used fragments here)

Comment: Do You want to make a Sliding Menu Effect by displaying the Second Activity Partially ?

Comment: @SalmanMuhammadAyub i want that, can you provide a link?

Comment: I dnt need a menu in this case. what I want is my 2nd screen to come n display partially

Comment: What content is present on your Second Screen that you want to show partially ?

Comment: Sliding Menu looks like this http://blog.gpsinsight.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/gpsi_android_app_04.jpg are you sure you don't want this ?

Comment: this is not what i want. 1st screen is my home page, 2nd screen is my cart. when i press the cart button then 2nd screen should come partially from right side of the screen by pushing 1st screen to  left side. at the end i want to show both my activity screens partially

Comment: If this is your Requirement then, you shouldn't follow the Different Activity approach. I suggest that you should implement both of these different Activities into a single Activity as different Views(Layouts) and display them side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Your Requirement is to partially Display an Overlapping Activity on an Existing Activity. This is Possible with Sliding Menu Library (Which does not mean to technically create a floating Activity, but to create a Floating View integrated within the Sliding Menu that will be displayed partially on top on an Activity).

In case, if you are regarding this as some sort of Default Menu then please take a look at this Image 
[image]

If this is your actual Requirement, then here are the details for you.

Sliding Menu Library is an OpenSource Library, you can use it for displaying a partially visible Sliding Menu on top of an Activity.

Here is the link of `Sliding Menu Lib` :
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

You can navigate to the `example` directory present in this Project for the demonstration of it's Usage. 
I hope thie helps :)

Comment: Please Share your suggestions, before voting down any Answer.

Comment: I want my second screen(not menu, its another activity screen) to popup from the right side of the screen

Comment: I think you have mistaken Activities with Views. It is not possible to have multiple Activities at the same time; Views - yes. Activities are registered in Manifest and can be started one at a time. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: It's an old library and is inconsistent with the latest Android design patterns. You should use navigation drawer instead.

Comment: guide me how to get the menu from right side of the screen

Comment: I agree with @Philio you should use NavigationDrawer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a `NavigationDrawer`.

You can find out more information on the Android developer site:

https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.htmlA

Comment: this is not what i want. 1st screen is my home page, 2nd screen is my cart. when i press the cart button then 2nd screen should come partially from right side of the screen by pushing 1st screen to left side. at the end i want to show both my activity screens partially.

Comment: i want this to come from right side of the screen not left side. I tried this but ddnt work, android:layout_gravity="right"